# Word drop: have a beer or two

Tags: terminology

What is it called when a word is dropped (or implied):
"Have a beer or two" == "Have a beer or two beers"

Does this phenomenon have a name? Any pointers on where to learn more about it are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be [Noun ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_ellipsis) or N-ellipsis:

> ... a mechanism that elides, or appears to elide, part of a noun phrase that can be recovered from context.